# Lot of errors while pushing App with Apple Watch support to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, iphone-developer-program

I've build a Apple Watch support for my app. But I got the following errors:

```
ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'xxxx/_WatchKitStub/WK' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1 for information on the iOS app bundle structure."
ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."
ERROR ITMS-90455: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
ERROR ITMS-90499: "Missing Apple Watch Extension. The application 'xxxxx' is missing its corresponding Apple Watch extension."
ERROR ITMS-90508: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key 'DTPlatformName' in bundle xxxx is invalid."
```

I've tried to fix this, but with a new project I got the same error's. What's going on?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same 6 errors after adding Apple Watch support to my app and trying to upload to the App Store for the first time. I'm guessing it's due to the initial project setup with the old APIs even though I'm using Xcode 6.4. Have you found an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just yesterday and the reason and solution was very simple:

I forgot to change the profiles for Watch App and Extension to distribution profiles. After changing that the errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same set of errors and found out that I caused them by capitalizing the first letter of the names of all .app and .appex files in the Product folder. The names were still lower case in various places in the plists (Build Settings) for my app extension, WatchKit Extension and WatchKit App. After capitalizing the first letters for Product Name and Info.plist File settings, I was able to submit to the App Store.

Note that my main iPhone/iPad app needed to remain lower case throughout, i.e. com.cambuilt.camtinerary.

Comment: I think I also had to change my target from my WatchKit App to the main iPhone/Pad app before creating the archive.

Comment: Still have not resolved the issue since iTunes Connect lists my app as "Invalid Binary" but have created support ticket for Apple and will let you know the response.

Comment: Delete de Apple Watch app from the main app's Copy bundle. Then build the app. Fixed for me. Don't know why, but it works and it's checked by Apple.

Comment: Did that as well and have a ticket in with Apple Support and awaiting a reply. Awaiting the release version of Xcode 7 if I don't get an answer in the meantime before re-adding my Apple Watch app.